# I read this novella before 1970 -- kid is befriended by alien kid who has a spaceship?

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

This was definitely aimed at YA or even earlier because the age of the main human character I think is pre-teenager, maybe as young as 9 or 10.

Anyway, the alien has a spaceship which can accommodate a human -- as I recall:

1. Food dispensers which produce things that taste strange but iirc the human likes the stuff and one thing I think he imbibed was a drink that tasted like mustard.
2. I think the ship had sort of electronic showers -- no water.

Definitely a self-contained book, less than 200 pages. Not a short story in a collection. Not a very famous story, I don't think, never heard anyone else mention it.

Not much else except definitely no violence. Just trying to find author/title to see how much is familiar if I read the story again after nearly 55 years.

Comment: Was there a "power wire" that provided energy for everything in the ship, from lights to FTL drive -- but that was destroyed by "moisture"?

Comment: @ZeissIkon neither thing iirc but that sounds like the kind of detail that might be in the book. Did you have a book in mind?

Comment: That would have made it *The Spaceship Under the Apple Tree* by Louis Slobodkin -- series starter published in 1952.

Comment: Some is the same (kid, friend child alien w/ship), but not sure about the rest (been a while): Robert A. Heinlein's 'Have Space Suit, Will Travel'